# How to parse additional XML attributes with JUnit Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, junit

I'm running testcases against several different hosts. With the Junit plugin in Jenkins I want to have an overview of all the failed tests. I want to see in a glance which testcase failed on which host. 
The Junit plugin parses classname, name and time from my junit.xml, but I want Junit to parse the target attribute as well. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Example junit.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name='tests from ..controls.sshdconfig.rb' tests='1' failed='1' failures='1'>
        <testcase key="value" name='testcase' classname='tests from ..controls.sshdconfig.rb.Anonymous' target='ssh://root@host.com:22' time='0.01092212'>
            <failure message='failure message'/>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```